# changing model attribute by string in Django

Tags: django

```
import json
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from main.models import Personnages
def store_data(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:
        value = request.POST.get("value")
        toChange = request.POST.get("name")
        id = request.POST.get("id") #A IMPORTER
        perso = Personnages.objects.get(id=id)
        perso.toChange = value
        perso.save()
        return HttpResponse(value+toChange)
    else :
        raise Http404
```

I have written this code but the problem is that this part does not work:

```
perso.toChange = value
```

This doesn't seem to work. I figure it is because I extract the string from JSON instead of the field.

This is the model for reference:

```
class Personnages(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Joueur = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    Nom = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Age = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Genre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Date de parution")
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to="imagePerso/", null=True)
```

Comment: Can you show your Personnages model?

Comment: in order to improve the quality of the question and to make it more useful to others, I'd recommend editing the title to something like: "changing model attribute by string in Django"

Comment: It's done. I have difficulties to put word on my problem ^^ Thank you for the proposal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are trying to set an attribute based on a dynamic value. You are looking for setattr method (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)

In your case, replace

```
perso.toChange = value
```

with

```
setattr(perso, toChange, value)
```

On an unrelated note, when writing python code, it is advisable to follow Python coding standards as stated in [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). For instance, toChange should be to_change and so on.

Comment: Almost there, but `setattr` is a standalone function, not a method: `setattr(perso, toChange, value)`.

Comment: It works, thank you ! I will notice about the coding standards, i am learning so it's hard to write a working code. I will wait for a standard code ^^

Comment: If you use a python friendly IDE or editor (Sublime, PyCharm...), it will automatically check for PEP-8 compliance... and it really makes it easier to ask for help